# How can I access the first element of JSON array data?

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm using ionic as a front end and Laravel as a back end. 
This is the returned JSON data from an API URL, I want to access just the first element which is a.jpg without anything else, I tried using `filenames.[0]` but it's just displaying `[` which means that it's calling the first character not the first element of the array.

**Here's the JSON data:**

```
[{"filenames":"[\"a.jpg\",\"b.jpg\",\"c.jpg\"]"}]
```

**Here's my .ts file**

```
    import { ApiLandingRecipesService} from '../api-landing-recipes.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.page.scss'],
})
export class LandingPagePage implements OnInit {
  datauser: any[];
  constructor( public api: ApiLandingRecipesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataUser();
  }
  async getDataUser() {
    await this.api.getDataUser()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.datauser =res;
        console.log(this.datauser);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

**and Here's my service file:**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

const apiUrl = "https://example.com/showimages";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiLandingRecipesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || [] ; }

  getDataUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `filenames` here is a string and not an array, which is why you're getting `[` when you try to access the first element.

You probably need to parse the value, here's an example (assuming `datauser`) is the JSON data you've shown us.

```
let filename = JSON.parse(datauser[0].filenames)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you & how I can convert it to an array? i read that I should parse the JSON data, but it's already parsed..isn't it?

Comment: I've added a solution, assuming that datauser is the json data.

Comment: where should I place this line " let filename = JSON.parse(datauser[0].filenames)[0] "
? 
in the .ts file under " console.log(this.datauser); " ?

Comment: Yes, this line should be added after you have fetched and assigned the value to ```datauser```. The ```filename``` variable here is the first element of the array, which you were trying to access.

Comment: Ok i placed it, and my .html file how can i call it? like this 
<img src="example.com/showimages{{data.filename}}"> ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I don't know the structure of your app or your API. You wanted to access the filename and I think that question is answered. Please confirm that the solution works for you (by console logging the ```filename``` variable).

Comment: thank u it displayed on the console but not on the display screen, please check why: 
here's my .html file: 
 <ion-card-header *ngFor="let data of filename">
        <p> {{data.filename}} </p>
      </ion-card-header>

Comment: That is not in the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `filenames` is indeed a string (a json string representation of the array) and not an array.

Try converting the string into an array first.

```
JSON.parse(filenames)[0]
```

Comment: Where in the code i should put this? 
in my .html file i'm accessing filenames like this: 

<img src="https://example.com/showimages/{{data.filenames[0]}}">

Comment: can you provide some more code? where does `data`come from?

Comment: I provided my .ts and my service code above. 
It's coming from an apiUrl which is "https://example.com/showimages" as raw data (JSON)
I've connected my ionic app with laravel using api & http

Comment: Unfortunately Im not familiar with ionic so I cant exactly tell you what to do. But my guess would be to process the data that is coming from example.com/showimages with Javascript and look for the filenames variable and convert it using the statement above

Comment: Is the JSON data you provided coming from this statement? `console.log(this.datauser);`

Comment: Btw the processed (and already parsed) response from the server should be `[{"filenames":["a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg"]}]` . It might be that you doubled JSON -> String procedure on the server side